# Copy data from specific cells, even if it is empty, from multiple workbooks to master workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, copy-paste

I need to copy even blank cells (to avoid input data from two workbooks in the same row), because the final output is going to be storing the data from each workbook to a single row.

```vb
Sub Copy_specific_Cells_From_other_workbooks_auto_RF()

Dim FileName$, sPath$
Dim wkbDest As Workbook, wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "D:\TSSRs\PO11\TSS Reports\WL TSSR\"
'sPath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\HP Laptop\Documents\Documents\Jobs\DIT\IDMB\Stack Overflow\okinawa\"

Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
'setting worksheet to improve readability
Set wsDest = wkbDest.Sheets("Master")

FileName = Dir(sPath)
Do While Len(FileName) > 0
    'open workbook for read only
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(sPath & FileName)
    'setting worksheet to improve readability
    Set wsSource = wkbSource.Sheets(2)
    
    wsSource.Range("B2").Copy
    wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    wsSource.Range("B4").Copy
    wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    wsSource.Range("B6").Copy
    wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    wsSource.Range("B7").Copy
    wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
   
    'not needed since we're closing the workbook; so it will be done automatically
    
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    wkbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    FileName = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy to Rows in Another Workbook

- Determine the last destination row (`dRow`) before the loop **only once**.
- At the beginning of the loop, increment the destination row by one so it becomes the currently available row where all the values from the cells of the current source worksheet will be written to.

```vb
Sub RetrieveCellsData()

    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    ' The following two arrays need to have the same number of elements.
    Dim sCells() As Variant: sCells = VBA.Array("B2", "B4", "B6", "B7")
    Dim dColumns() As Variant: dColumns = VBA.Array("I", "J", "K", "L")
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Master")
    ' Determine the last destination row ('dRow').
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Pick another column if necessary or use another way, e.g.:
    'With dws.UsedRange
    '    dRow = .Columns(1).Cells(.Rows.Count).Row
    'End With
    
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = sFolderPath
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> pSep Then sPath = sPath & pSep
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sPath)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sCells) ' or UBound(dColumns)
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        dRow = dRow + 1 ' All source cell values will be written to this row,
        ' whether they're empty or not i.e. don't 'xlUp' in the loop!
        sFilePath = sPath & sFileName
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, , True) ' read-only
        Set sws = swb.Sheets(2) ' pretty risky!
        For n = 0 To nUpper
            dws.Cells(dRow, dColumns(n)).Value = sws.Range(sCells(n)).Value
        Next n
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Cells' data retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```